# "Host key verification failed. fatal: Could not read from remote repository." when trying "yarn install"

Tags: javascript, reactjs, github, npm, yarnpkg

I have been developing a webapp, but today, suddenly "yarn install" stopped working.

The console says "Host key verification failed. fatal: Could not read from remote repository." when trying "yarn install".

I tried with several PCs and laptops that I had no problem using them until now, but they all failed with the same error message.

I re-cloned the whole repo several times and again I had no luck.

This command also did not work.

```
ssh-keyscan -t rsa github.com >> ~/.ssh/known_hosts
```

I would very much appreciate your help.. This is so frustrating.

Answer (score 0):

Add the following ssh key entries from:

https://docs.github.com/en/authentication/keeping-your-account-and-data-secure/githubs-ssh-key-fingerprints

to your target machines: ~/.ssh/known_hosts

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).